# Why did the signs inverse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Shouldn't it be $+ 12x$ and $-27$, not the other way around? How did this happen?

Comment: No: Distribute the $-3$ and note that $(-3)(-12x) = +36x$.

Comment: $-3\times-12=+36$

Answer (score 2):

The signs did not inverse. Let us start with the original expression $$-3x^2+36x-81$$ $36$ and $81$ are multiple of $3$, so $3$ can be factored out and the expression becomes $$3(-x^2+12x-27)$$ Now, multiply the outside term by $-1$ and the inside term by $-1$ which shall not change anything since $-1 \times -1=+1$. So, we arrive to $$-3(x^2-12x+27)$$

Answer (score 1):

In "slow motion":
$$-3x^2 + 36x - 81$$
Factor integers:
$$(-3)x^2 + (-3 \cdot -12)x - (-3 \cdot -27)$$
Shuffle parentheses:
$$(-3)x^2 + (-3) \cdot (-12x) - (-3) \cdot (-27)$$
Un-distribute (factor):
$$(-3)(x^2 + (-12x) - (-27))$$
Rewrite signs:
$$(-3)(x^2 - 12x + 27)$$

Alternatively, another way to think about it:
$$-3x^2 + 36x - 81 = 3(-x^2 + 12x - 27) = \color{red}-3 \cdot \color{red}-(-x^2 + 12x - 27) = -3 \cdot (x^2 - 12x + 27)$$